# Exception when inserting data into a DFS table

Tags: insert, sql-insert, dolphindb

I insert data using the following script, but the number of inserted rows is 0. What’s the problem?

```
tmp = table('device_demo' as device_id,2022.02.23 11:02:01 as data_time,23.1 as temperature,0.05 as pressure);
t = loadTable('dfs://rangedb','device_db')
tableInsert(t,tmp);
```

Answer (score 0):

For DFS tables partitioned by range, inserted data beyond the range will be ignored. You can use function `addRangePartitions` to append new values to the partition scheme.